# Batch script to display variable content in mail body

Tags: batch-file

I have batch script which displays the variable content (%Build%) in a mail body.

for example if the Varaible content is having:
%Build%= aa001.skc

the mail which is triggered by the script has the mail body as below (OUTPUT).

"Skip file generated for the files aa001.skc"

(Imagine test.log contains the value aa001.skc in it)

below is my current script for the same:

```html
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%x in (C:\Users\Desktop\test.log) do (
set Build=%%x
echo %Build%
)

"blat.exe" -to "abc@gmail.com" -cc "abc@gmail.com","xyz@gmail.com" -f 123@test.com -body "Skip file generated for the files %Build%" -subject "Skip file found" -server mailout.xyz.com

exit
```

But if the test.log contains values as

aa001.skc

aa002.skc

aa003.skc

with the above script my output is showing only as below in the mail body.
Current output:
"Skip file generated for the files aa003.skc" (Its taking the last value,  not sure how to put it in for loop in mail body)

But my OUTPUT of the mail body should be like below.

"Skip file generated for the files

aa001.skc

aa002.skc

aa003.skc"

Kindly help me achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal for batch files to commence with a `setlocal` instruction which effectively ensures that the environment remains unchanged at the end of the batch, so running successive batches does not accumulate changes to contaminate for further batch executions.

To fix your process - version 1

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%x in (C:\Users\Desktop\test.log) do (
 call set "Build=%%x %%build%%"
 call echo %%Build%%
)
blat ......
```

(in this one, the `setlocal` is not strictly necessary - I'm assuming it's being `call`ed from another batch)

[EDIT: to add newlines]
Poorly-documented featue of BLAT is that a pipe character (`|`) in the body is transformed to a newline, hence

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "build=|"
for /f "delims=" %%x in (C:\Users\Desktop\test.log) do (
 call set "Build=%%x|%%build%%"
 call echo %%Build%%
)
blat ......
```

You may also wish to insert a pipe just after `%build%` in the `-body` parameter.

[end-edit]

Another common way is to use `delayedexpansion`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in (C:\Users\Desktop\test.log) do (
 set "Build=%%x !build!"
 echo !Build!
)
blat ......
```

(setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`required, notice the`call`s have gone.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence - actually something you didn't say. Your code should have shown the original value of `build` three times. Now - if this had been retained from an earlier run, it would have shown the last value three times. If on the other hand you had a clean environment, then since `build` would not have been set, you should have seen `echo is off` three times.

See endless SO items on `delayedexpansion` for more info.

Comment: I used setlocal enabledelayedexpansion..  I Just have one more doubt. Now my output is coming like below: Skip file generated for the files aa003.skc aa002.skc aa001.skc. How can i display it aa00*.skc one in each line. as mentioned above. instead in a single line?